# where does genetic material for antibody production come from?

Tags: immunology, immune-system

All antibodies are proteins and like every other protein, mRNA codes for them. So acquired immunity, is acquired, which means that information was not previously present in our DNA before exposure to the pathogens.

So my question is, does our DNA in some way get modified or something else? Where does the new genetic material come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does our DNA in some way get modified or something else?

Yes. The DNA gets modified. [VDJ recombination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V(D)J_recombination) and [somatic hypermutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somatic_hypermutation) are the mechanisms by which this happens.

You can find an entire book chapter/review on these topics. So I shall not elaborate further.

Comment: thank you ... i don't mean to delve further into this I just wanted to know the broad concept . thanks a lot